# Mac OS X El Capitain shutdown from the Apple menu doesn’t work but it works via shell

Tags: macos, shutdown, launchd

My problem is related to the shutdown. If I shutdown normally (Apple Icon -> Shut Down…) it doesn't work. Whereas it works via shell:

```
sudo shutdown halt
```

After many Googling, (guess what?) nothing has been found. But I found something interesting in my console log. I have a script launched by launchd which tries to connect to a server every 10 sec.

Screenshot of the console log:

[image: SCREEN OF THE CONSOLE LOG]

I uninstalled AVerTV days ago and a I can't find a `uninstall.app` to perfectly clean this. So my question is could `com.AVerMedia.AVerQuick` be the process that is preventing a normal shutdown? Or it is just another bug?

And—FYI—iff I run Mac OS X in safe mode It goes shutdown normally.

Answer (score 0):

It is *very possible* that `averTV` is not completely removed. The console log shows some hints about the problem. Another clue is that safe mode fixes the shutdown problem.

Here's a quick fix that might help. Look for `com.AVerMedia.AVerQuick.plist` or a file with a similar name in these folders:

- ~/Library/LaunchAgents
- ~/Library/LaunchDaemons
- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons

If you find files like `com.AVerMedia.AVerQuick`, drag them to the Trash and restart (or `sudo shutdown halt`).